# NameError: global name 'os' is not defined in keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples despite importing os

Tags: python, keras

Here are the imports at the top of my code

```
import os
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Found 33 images belonging to 2 classes.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imggen.py", line 29, in <module>
    save_format = 'jpeg'):
  File "/home/psdanielxu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py", line 111, in next
    return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
  File "/home/psdanielxu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py", line 245, in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples
    img.save(os.path.join(self.save_to_dir, fname))
NameError: global name 'os' is not defined
```

I'm unsure how this error is persisting because I have imported os

Comment: Could you post the code of `imggen.py`?? The error is in line 29 of that file??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the github of keras-preprocessing, and it seem like they missed the import there.
Try adding the `import os` on the `iterator.py` file this file is located at `/home/psdanielxu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py` on your system

If this works for you, you should also go to the project's github and open an issue on this bug. (https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/issues)